# I have the following error:android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent

I have a MainActivity with a list and when it occurs
A certain condition opens an alert dialog.

The problem is that when you open the alert dialog you have to bring
the data of a variable and put it in a textview that I have in the alertDialog
the case is that it gives me this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference

The MainActivity code where I do the Intent is:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ConfirmacionAlarma.class);                
 intent.putExtra("notificar",totales);
```

And just after I call alertDialog

```
 new ConfirmacionAlarma(contexto);
```

The AlertDialog code is this:

```
    public class ConfirmacionAlarma extends AppCompatActivity {


    public ConfirmacionAlarma(Context contexto)
    {

    final Dialog dialogo = new Dialog(contexto);
    dialogo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialogo.setCancelable(false);
    dialogo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.dialogo_alarma);


    final TextView notiAlarm = (TextView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.notificacionAlarma);

    TextView descAlarm = (TextView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.DescAlarma);
    TextView contAla = (TextView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.ContadorAlarmas);
    EditText fechaAlar = (EditText) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.Fecha);
    ImageView camapana = (ImageView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.image1);
    Button ConfirmarAviso = (Button) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.Aceptar);




    ConfirmarAviso.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialogo.dismiss();
        }
    });
    Bundle nuevoTotales = getIntent().getExtras();
    String nom = nuevoTotales.getString("notificar");
    notiAlarm.setText(nom);
    dialogo.show();


   }
```

It tells me that what the object brings is Null but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get data from the `constructor` of the `Activity`. You should get data in **onCreate** method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  String value;
  Intent intent=this.getIntent();
   if(intent != null){
   value = intent.getStringExtra("notificar");
   }
}
```

Comment: But where? In the MainActivity or in the alertdialog?

Comment: Alertdialog activity onCreate method.

Comment: I put the Oncreate in the alertdialog but it gives me an error: Saying that I have to call super.onCreate.
I don't know how to solve this.